# Javascript - range of 5 around index in array

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to do the follow.

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to retrieve a set amount eg of them around a given index.

Here's an example.

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var index = 0;
var max = 5;

If the index is 0 I want [0 - 4]
If the index is 4 I want [2 - 6]
If the index is 9 I want [6 - 10]
```

But I also want it to work if the array is smaller then the max too. Eg

```
var arr = [0,1,2];
var index = 0;
var max = 5;

Any index would return [0 - 2]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The second one should return 0-3 although there's only 0-2 in the array? How should this work? Will it guess?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it should return 0 - 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/MJnXV/3/)

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getRange(array, index, range) {
    var least = index - Math.floor(range/2);
    least = (least < 0) ? 0 : least;
    return array.slice(least, least+range);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = index - max / 2;
if (start < 0) start = 0;
var end = start + max;
if (end > arr.length) {
  end = arr.length;
  start = end - max;
  if (start < 0) start = 0;
}
var result = arr.slice(start, end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Riateche. I have tried slice. My problem is that I want the index to appear in the middle of the range. So if I have an index of 2 I should get the two results to the left and two to the right where possible. But I always want 5 results where possible too.

Comment: this only goes forward from the index, not backwards

Comment: You may also want to check if `index + max > arr.length`, in order to fulfill this wish: *If the index is 9 I want [6 - 10]*